# Nsis: Change Title bar for Two installations in one installer

Tags: nsis

I have two installations in one installer from:
http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Two_installations_in_one_installer
How can I customize the title bar (setup name) for the two installations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSIS is not really designed to do this so you have to set it manually every time a page changes:

```
!include MUI.nsh
!include WinMessages.nsh
Caption " "

!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW lic1
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "${__FILE__}"
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW inst1
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW lic2
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "${__FILE__}"
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW inst2
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English

Function lic1
SendMessage $HWNDPARENT ${WM_SETTEXT} 0 "STR:Foo$(^LicenseSubCaption)"
FunctionEnd
Function inst1
SendMessage $HWNDPARENT ${WM_SETTEXT} 0 "STR:Foo$(^InstallingSubCaption)"
FunctionEnd
Function lic2
SendMessage $HWNDPARENT ${WM_SETTEXT} 0 "STR:Bar$(^LicenseSubCaption)"
FunctionEnd
Function inst2
SendMessage $HWNDPARENT ${WM_SETTEXT} 0 "STR:Bar$(^InstallingSubCaption)"
FunctionEnd
```